# Shell generic equivalent of Bash Substring replacement ${foo/a/b}

Tags: bash, shell, find, sh

Is there a shell-independent equivalence of Bash substring replacement:

```
foo=Hello
echo ${foo/o/a} # will output "Hella"
```

Most of the time I can use `bash` so that is not a problem, however when combined with `find -exec` it does not work. For instance, to rename all `.cpp` files to `.c`, I'd like to use:

```
# does not work
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec mv {} {/.cpp$/.c}
```

For now, I'm using:

```
# does work, but longer
while read file; do 
    mv "$file" "${file/.cpp$/.c}"; 
done <<< $(find . -name '*.cpp')
```

Ideally a solution that could be used in scripts is better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `find` and `-exec` you can do this:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; mv "$f" "${f/.cpp/.c}"' - '{}' \;
```

However this will fork `bash -c` for each filename so using `xargs` or a `for` loop like this is better for performance reasons:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do 
    mv "$file" "${file/.cpp/.c}" 
done < <(find . -name '*.cpp' -print0)
```

Comment: Confirming it does not work as well on MacOSX, version `3.2.57(1)`.

Comment: @anubhava my bad, I missed the `- '{}'` part. Do you have any documentation about what it does please?

Comment: [**Here is a working demo of above find command**](http://ideone.com/uZwywZ) btw I do have `GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)` as well and it worked fine there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, an alternative to using `bash` would be to use `rename`. If you have the *cool* version of the `rename` command, which is shipped along with `perl` you can do:

```
find -name '*.cpp' -exec rename 's/\.cpp$/.c/' {} +
```

The above example assumes that you have GNU `findutils`, having this you don't need to pass the current directory since it is the default. If you don't have GNU `findutils`, you need to explicitly pass it:

```
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec rename 's/\.cpp$/.c/' {} +
```

Comment: Did you test it? The .cpp$ seems to not work for me.

Comment: Not really, because of lack of test files. Let me prepare a small test.

Comment: Single and double quotes have to be switched, too.

Comment: Thanks for the `rename` tip alternative piped with `find`. But you are missing folder in which to apply the find command: `find .` instead of `find`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks. However, quoting it should work as well. (Added that)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Good point, you are right. I'll delete the post.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ok, kept that.

Comment: @Cqnqrd `find` defaults to `.`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. not the one on MacOSX 10.11.3 at least. But it may be Apple specific issue, I dunno.

Comment: @Cqnqrd Or defaulting is a GNU extension. Looks like POSIX `find` requires a path argument.